# I'm trying to get a specific image based on the id of a pojo in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

The problem is here. I am trying to get the folder from the id of the object.
For example, i'd like the photo from images/1/1.jpg
prop.id has the id of the property, which will have photos of it in the images/{id} folder.

```html
<img class="card-img-top" src="images/${prop.id}/1.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
```

```java
Property property = new Property(1,null,"description single", null);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView messages(Model model) {
        PropertiesDao prop = new PropertiesDao();
        List<Property> x= prop.getAll();
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("newhome");
        model.addAttribute("multipleProperty",x );
        model.addAttribute("property", property);
        return mav;
    }
```

This is the code i'm trying to make work.
The Property class has id and description i'm interested in at the moment. I'd like that based on the id, to get the specific folder named 1 in resources/static/images/1

```
<div class="col-sm-3" th:each="prop: ${multipleProperty}">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/${prop.id}/1.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title" th:text="${prop.description}">Sample Card Title</h4>
                    <p class="card-text" th:text="${prop.id}">He seems sinking under the evidence could
                        not only grieve and a visit. The father is to bless and placed in
                        his length hid...</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Tell me more &rarr;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```java
package com.generic.components;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

public class Property {

    private int id;
    private List<String> images;
    private String description;
    private List<Rooms> rooms;
    public Property(int id, List<String> images, String description, List<Rooms> rooms) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.images = images;
        this.description = description;
        this.rooms = rooms;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public List<String> getImages() {
        return images;
    }
    public void setImages(List<String> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public List<Rooms> getRooms() {
        return rooms;
    }
    public void setRooms(List<Rooms> rooms) {
        this.rooms = rooms;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Property [id=%s, images=%s, description=%s, rooms=%s]", id, images, description, rooms);
    }



}
```

I have succeded in extracting the variable id from the object, but i can't make thymeleaf recognize images/${prop.id}/1.jpg as images/1/1.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add `th:` for img src:

```
<img class="card-img-top" th:src="${'images/' + prop.id + '/1.jpg'}" alt="Card image cap">
```